# Install a .deb completely 'by hand'

Tags: dpkg, maemo

So, I recently acquired a brand new Nokia N900 phone off of an online auction site for a fairly reasonable price. The N900 is a Linux phone, and it came out a long time ago, but it's only just now within my budget.

I've spent the past day struggling with it. Its version of `apt` is particularly frustrating.

The point I'm at now is, I can't get `dpkg` to properly configure a package because of how some guy at Nokia decided the phone shouldn't have any files whatsoever in `/usr/share/doc`. Apparently. And the `--configure` of this particular package demands that a file be put into `/usr/share/doc` and then "optified", which is a Nokia Linux term I don't really understand, but seems mainly to have to do with treating `/opt/maemo` as if it were the root directory when it comes to certain types of files.

Needless to say, this documentation can not be "optified"... I don't really care why, I just want to be able to:

- Decompress the `.deb` file myself.
- Look at the script that tells `dpkg` where to put things.
- *Modify the script and/or move those files around myself.*
- Do whatever else is necessary so that the right files are in the right place, *myself*.
- *Inform the list of packages that this package has been 'installed'.*
- Get on with my life, knowing a lot more about `.deb`s than I currently do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the `.deb` file by hand, and then install it as if were the original one.

You could take a look to the [official reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)

The steps I did in some moment in the past, could be summarized as:

1. Create a working directory:

   ```
   mkdir work
   cd work
   ```
2. Make sure that a copy of the `.deb` file is in that directory.
3. Decompress the `.deb` file:

   ```
   ar x $DEB_FILE
   ```
4. Remove the `.deb` file from here:

   ```
   rm $DEB_FILE
   ```
5. Decompress the data file:

   ```
   mkdir data
   cd data
   tar zxf ../data.tar.gz
   cd ..
   ```
6. Decompress the control file:

   ```
   mkdir control
   cd control
   tar zxf ../control.tar.gz
   cd ..
   ```
7. Do whatever change you have to do, for example, modify at least one of the files inside control directory:

   - control/preinst
   - control/postinst
   - control/prerm
   - control/postrm
8. Update into `control/md5sums` the md5 checksums of the files you modified.
9. Compress again the `.deb` file:

   ```
   cd control
   tar zcf control.tar.gz *
   mv control.tar.gz ..
   cd ..
   rm -rf control

   cd data
   tar zcf data.tar.gz *
   mv data.tar.gz ..
   cd ..        
   rm -rf data

   ar r $DEB_FILE debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the postinst scripts in /var/lib/dpkg/info.  Fix the script so it doesn't fail, and have `dpkg` configure the package again.  No need to bother with manually unpacking the package.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [deb2targz](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/deb/) to uncompress `.deb` file and manually move files to proper locations.