# Install kernel .deb file without using dpkg

Tags: linux-kernel, deb

I'm running Manjaro (Derived from Arch). I have a .deb file for kernel 4.0. Is it possible to install the kernel from this file, and what are the steps involved?

I tried opening the .deb file and from the look of it I might just be able to copy the kernel files to the corresponding directories and just do an update-grub to get it running. Will that work?

P.S. I'm new to Manjaro, but mostly fluent in Linux.

Comment: It almost certainly *won't* because those dependencies that are keeping you from installing it with `dpkg` are there for a *reason*. You may very well be lacking critically important software it needs.

Comment: Don't use debian packages on archlinux. If you want a custom kernel for your arch distrib, look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Arch_Build_System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Install a .deb completely 'by hand'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66533/install-a-deb-completely-by-hand) but in this case I would recommend against that approach: the kernel packages rely on a certain amount of infrastructure to build the appropriate initrd for your system, and I think it would be very difficult to get it working manually...

If you really want kernel 4.0 and can't wait for the appropriate AUR, you'd be better off building a kernel from the upstream source code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Just before seeing your answer I had tried to manually extract all the files to relevant directories. Made the initrd. It booted to a rescue prompt. :) As you suggested I'll try compiling from source. Thanks again :)

Comment: Look for a software package called `kernel-package` then run `make-kpkg` in an existing linux kernel source tree.

Comment: @Shadur not on Arch Linux...

Comment: ... Archlinux doesn't *use* debian packages to begin with. Use the actual package manager and actual packages meant to go with it.

Comment: @Shadur exactly, which is why I don’t understand why you’re suggesting looking for `kernel-package` and running `make-kpkg`.

Comment: Because you mentioned "deb" more explicitly than you did "archlinux" and I assumed that that means that the distribution you were using actually *uses* .deb. Because trying to install a kernel deb on a system that doesn't even use debs would be **stupid**.

Comment: @Shadur please read my answer a little more carefully: “I would recommend against that approach”, “If you really want kernel 4.0 and can't wait for the appropriate AUR”. I’m not trying to explain how to proceed on Debian. You should tell the OP that he is stupid, shouldn’t you? But that’s not how we go about things around here (which I would imagine you know, given your rep).